# How to find Laurent series of exp(1/z+z)

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

My approach was to expand both $e^{1/z}$ and $e^{z}$, and multiply them together, but it seems like a lot of work, is there any shortcut that I can use in solving this problem?

Comment: There are many [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) (just like for Taylor series). I guess you mean the series about the point $z=0$ ?

Comment: Since $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, I think it has to be around another point.

Comment: @RolfHoyer There is no problem expaning about an essential singularity: $e^{1/z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!z^n}$.

Comment: My mistake, I never realized that Laurent series need not be formal Laurent series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so much work. Since:
$$ e^{z} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{z^n}{n!},$$
$$ e^{\frac{1}{z}} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!z^m}$$
for any $h\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that the coefficient of $x^h$ in their product is given by:
$$\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(m+h)!m!}=I_h(2)$$
where $I_h$ is a [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). That gives:

> $$ \exp\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right) = I_0(2)+\sum_{h\geq 1} I_h(2)\left(z^h+\frac{1}{z^h}\right).$$